# MATLAB: modified mvnrnd output

Tags: matlab, normal-distribution

I have the following piece of code that creates a `100x2` population vector, evaluates the population against a function `f`, and then creates a new population based on the top 10 population members who obtained the lowest function scores:

```
N = 100;
N_elite = 0.1*N;
dim = 2;

a = 0;
b = 3;
x = (b-a).*rand(N, dim)+a;

f = @(x) x(:,1).^2 + x(:,2).^2;
cost = f(x)
population_cost = [x,cost]

x_sorted = sortrows(population_cost,dim+1)
x_elite = x_sorted(1:N_elite,:)

mu = mean(x_elite(:,[1:dim]))
sigma = cov(x_elite(:,[1:dim]))
x = mvnrnd(mu,sigma,N)
```

The code uses `mvnrnd` to create the new population. I'm hoping to have a new population vector that has the following property: `x(:,1)<x(:,2)`, that is, each value in the first column must be lower than each value in the second column. Is there a property/option in `mvnrnd` that allows for this, instead of having to use a for loop to check each row and perform a switch if `x(i,1)>x(i,2)`?

Comment: The requirement you specify is incompatible with the output having a multivariate Gaussian distribution. So no, `mvnrnd` can't do that

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to modify `mvnrnd` for that, you can simply use `sort` to sort `x` along the 2nd dimension (columns):

```
% sort x columns such that x(i,1) < x(i,2) for all i
x = sort(x,2,'ascend');
% check
all(x(:,1) < x(:,2)) % yes
```